# Laravel eloquent: Update A Model And its Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

With an eloquent model you can update data simply by calling

```
$model->update( $data );
```

But unfortunately this does not **update the relationships.**

If you want to update the relationships too you will need to assign each value manually and call [push()](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete) then:

```
$model->name = $data['name'];
$model->relationship->description = $data['relationship']['description'];
$model->push();
```

Althrough this works it will become a mess if you have a lot of data to assign.

I am looging for something like

```
$model->push( $data ); // this should assign the data to the model like update() does but also for the relations of $model
```

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: There is no method for this, but have you tried something like this: `$model->relationship->fill($data['relationship']); ` then `push` ?

Comment: Thats what I currently do but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do so :)

Comment: There is no other way, as Eloquent currently doesn't know what relations are on the model until you call them as dynamic property, load with `load` method, eager load etc. (push works only with loaded relations that are present in model's `relations` array)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can implement the [observer pattern](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-observers) to catch the "updating" eloquent's event.

First, create an observer class:

```
class RelationshipUpdateObserver {

    public function updating($model) {
        $data = $model->getAttributes();

        $model->relationship->fill($data['relationship']);

        $model->push();
    }

}
```

Then assign it to your model

```
class Client extends Eloquent {

    public static function boot() {

        parent::boot();

        parent::observe(new RelationshipUpdateObserver());
    }
}
```

And when you will call the update method, the "updating" event will be fired, so the observer will be triggered.

```
$client->update(array(
  "relationship" => array("foo" => "bar"),
  "username" => "baz"
));
```

See the [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events) for the full list of events.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is (imo) the best solution to this problem

Comment: getAttributes() method does not return a relationship index

Answer (score 6):

You may try something like this, for example a `Client` model and an `Address` related model:

```
// Get the parent/Client model
$client = Client::with('address')->find($id);

// Fill and save both parent/Client and it's related model Address
$client->fill(array(...))->address->fill(array(...))->push();
```

There are other ways to save relation. You may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23972017/ardent-laravel-auto-hydrate-relation/23975166#23975166) for more details.