# How to clone an eloquent object with all relations in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, activerecord, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to make a clone from existing eloquent model with all its relations without using loops on relations because i may extend relations in future. For now i have an order model:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');
$table->timestamps();
```

and order has many items:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('quantity');
```

there is another relations 'sell_orders:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
```

but i know it should be more than these in future. How can i make a clone from an order and all its relations? I found this code:

```
$order = Order::find(1);
$clone = $order->replicate();
$clone->push();
$clone->save();
```

This make a new model without any relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Observer Pattern** to update records with relationship.Refer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200089/laravel-eloquent-update-a-model-and-its-relationships)

Answer (score -2):

If i unterstand u correct, try the following:
`$clone = $order` ?
:D